# Update from group query without creating a physical table

Tags: ms-access, select, group-by, temp-tables

I have a table named ECD which is like this:

```
Cle2                 Mont           Lettrage
acbd....            +8,36            Suspens    
abcd...             -8,36            Suspens
dced..              +12,89          Suspens
dced..              -12,89           Suspens
```

Where 
`Cle2` is the field that identifies the records in the table which belong to the same group 
`Mont` is the field that stores the amount per record
`Lettrage` is the field that stores a label that will change according to the resut of my query.

What I have to do is basically group the table ECD by Cle2 and in the meanwhile sum the values of Mont (`Sum(Mont)`) then check if the values in Mont summed and grouped by `cle2` are equal to zero or not. If they are equal to zero, I update `Lettrage` labelling those records as OK, if not I label those records as SUSPENS!

I've already done this in access but the code is not so efficient what I basically do is :

1, Create a new table called `provisional` 
2, Insert into this table the values of the select Query

Code:

```
INSERT INTO Provisor
SELECT Cle2 As Cle2p, Sum(MONTANT_ORACLE) AS Sum 
FROM ECD 
GROUP BY Cle2
```

3, Create a table ECD2, empty, with the same fields as ECD 
4, Insert into this table the result of the join statement like this:

Code:

```
INSERT INTO ECDlet1 
SELECT Provisor.lettrage As Let2, ecd.*
FROM Provisor 
LEFT JOIN ECD ON Provisor.[Cle2p]=ECD.Cle2
```

5, Then clean the db and update the `Lettrage` with the right label

So what I'd like to do is do something like this without creating all those stupid physical tables
I want to underline that I execute the query in the Visual Basic by using The CurrentDb.Execute statement.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
UPDATE ECD 
SET ECD.lettrage = IIf(DSum("Mont","ECD","cle2='" & [cle2] & "'")=0,"Ok","Suspens");
```